How to handle back event properly in Jetpack Compose Android?
I've a special case that I need to override default back behavior only when a condition is met, and I've implemented it but, doesn't work when the NavigationDrawer is open!
I'm expecting the BackHandler to work when NavigationDrawer is closed and NavHost is showing a particular destination.
The code I have (minimal):
Manifest
android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"

Code
val navController = rememberNavController()
val currentDestination by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val isDisabledScreen = remember(currentDestination) {
    currentDestination?.toRoute<DisabledDestination>() != null
}
val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
val canOverrideBack = remember(
    drawerState.isClosed,
    isDisabledScreen,
) {
    drawerState.isClosed && isDisabledScreen
}
BackHandler(enabled = canOverrideBack) {
    context.findActivity()?.finish()
}
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet(
            drawerState = drawerState,
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
) {
    Scaffold(
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = HomeDestination,
        ) {
            HomeScreen()
            DisabledScreen()
            // ...
        }
    }
}

and my start destination is HomeDestination. When app starts, user will be navigated to DisabledDestination if a certain condition meets. Now, if on DisabledDestination, when back is pressed, app should exit/finish.
But, this doesn't work in any of following case:

On DisabledDestination and drawerState.isClosed:
Here, NavHost handles back event and user goes to startDestination.
On DisabledDestination and drawerState.isOpen:
Here, NavHost handles back event and user goes to startDestination.

In both cases, once back on startDestination, NavigationDrawer handles back event if open else NavHost handles by closing the app.
TLDR: I'm expecting the app to close if on DisabledDestination but, also close the NavigationDrawer if open before closing the app (which is in-built and works but, at wrong place) and user should never see the startDestination if ever gets on DisabledDestination.

You should override the back handler inside the NavHost:
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
//...
composable<DisabledDestination> {
    BackHandler {
        if (drawerState.isClosed) {
            context.findActivity()?.finish()
        } else {
            scope.launch {
                drawerState.close()
            }
        }
    }
    DisabledScreen()
}

Edit:
Instead of dealing with BackHandler, you can just remove startDestination from the backstack when navigating from HomeDestination to DisabledDestination. This will enable predictive back gesture for both ModalNavigationDrawer and DisabledDestination (unlike context.findActivity()?.finish())
composable<HomeDestination> {
    HomeScreen(
        navigate = {
            navController.navigate(DisabledDestination) {
                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

Edit 2:
Let's try to figure out what is happening when you add a BackHandler to a navigation destination without clearing navigation back stack. First, it's important to remember that only the last added enabled back handler is executed. From the docs:

the callbacks are invoked in the reverse order from the order you add them—the callback added last is the first given a chance to handle the Back button event.


Callbacks follow the Chain of Responsibility pattern. Each callback in the chain is invoked only if the preceding callback was not enabled.

ModalNavigationDrawer and NavHost add their own PredictiveBackHandlers. So, if we our code is structured like this:
ModalNavigationDrawer {
  NavHost {
    // Custom
    BackHandler {
    }
  }
}

We will have 3 back handlers that are going to be checked in the reverse order: CustomBH -> NavHostBH -> DrawerBH. DrawerBH is active when the drawer is open (src). NavHostBH is active when its navigation back stack has more than 1 destination (src).
If CustomBH is always enabled - it's easy, it handles every back press. But this comes with a drawback - manually closing the drawer or the app disables the predictive back behavior. So what happens if we disable CustomBH when the drawer is open?
In this case, back press dispatcher will check the next back handler - NavHostBH. It will be enabled, because there are other destinations on the navigation back stack (HomeDestination) and it will navigate us back to HomeDestination. Important moment: this will also remove CustomBH from the back press dispatcher! So now it's only NavHostBH -> DrawerBH. It will also disable NavHostBH, because there is only 1 destination in the navigation back stack now. So, the next back press will close the drawer (and disable DrawerBH), and the next one will close the app.

thanks for your answer but, I don't want to close the drawer using .close() because it comes with predictive back support out of the box. I want to only close the app when drawer is not open else let navigation drawer handle the back event through predictive back.

How about setting DisabledDestination as the new navigation root? You'll have predictive back for closing the app too, check out my edit @dev.tejasb

actually I've multiple of such screens in which I need mentioned behaviour and just setting one of those as startDestination will not solve the problem as app could decide to navigate to one of the other such screens. I was wondering why is my code not working as expected! and why is NavHost's back handling has priority over NavigationDrawer's?

Your code doesn't work because your back handler ends up on the bottom of the stack of back handlers, below the ones of ModalNavigationDrawer' and NavHost, and only the top active back handler is called. NavHost's is active when there are destinations to pop, and ModalNavigationDrawer's is active when drawer is open. So your back handler is only called when drawer is closed on HomeScreen. @dev.tejasb

You can add a function like NavController.navigateToDisabledScreen with nav back stack clearing for each of those destinations and only use these functions to navigate. In fact, you can add such functions for each screen to encapsulate navigation details. I think clearing nav back stack is cleaner and easier way, and it corresponds with the app's navigation logic. @dev.tejasb

as you are saying in your comment, my back handler will be active only on HomeScreen when drawer is closed but, my back handler is active even when drawer is open!! that's something I'm not getting!

yes, current priority of back handling is as: nav host > nav drawer > my handler. I don't know how!

It doesn't matter if your handler is active or not, it won't be called if there are other active handlers on top of it. Only one back handler is called for each back press. @dev.tejasb

you're right. what I'm expecting: startDestination is HomeScreen. it decides to either stay or go to one of other screens from where app will close on back press. consider I also have nav drawer and I'm expecting predictive back everywhere possible. now, even if I add back handlers in each of those other screens, app will close but, it also closes the app if the drawer is open. so, I'm using enabled = canOverrideBack = isDrawerClosed but, still not working.

It's important to note that our BackHandler is removed when we navigate away from the destination. I've added some explanation to the answer, hope it clears things up @dev.tejasb
